Radiation energy and momentum relation
Why is $\rho = 3p$ for radiation? What is the intuition behind this? If we had only 2 spatial dimentions, would it be $\rho = 2p$?
(I came across this relation while studying the state of the universe, used in Friedman Equations.)

Have you checked the Wikipedia page?

It doesn’t answer my question.

Simply stating "it doesn’t answer my question" and "intuition behind this" is very vague. Please be more specific about which step you don't understand.
